# Advent calendar using Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make an advent calendar using Bootstrap 3.3.7 similar to the one here http://2015.itsashapechristmas.co.uk/

The markup I'm using is

```
<div class="container">

      <div class="row grid">
          <div class="col-md-2 grid-item">1</div>
          <div class="col-md-2 grid-item">2</div>
          <div class="col-md-2 grid-item">3</div>
          <div class="col-md-2 grid-item">4</div>
          <div class="col-md-2 grid-item">5</div>
          <div class="col-md-2 grid-item">6</div>
      </div>

      <!-- Repeat --> 

</div>
```

Where I've put  `<!-- Repeat -->`  I'm using similar columns of 6 numbers inside `.col-md-2`

I wanted to make the numbers appear centered and square (as per the example link) so used this:

```
.grid {
    font-size: 48px;
}
.grid-item {
    padding: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Ideally I wanted this to collapse into smaller columns when the viewport is resized, but at the breakpoint for `.col-md-2` it just collapses into a single column.

Am I doing this the correct way or are there better ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add more classes to your div. Something like `col-xs-6` which would give you 2 equal columns on the extra small viewport and `col-sm-4`which would give you three equal columns on small viewports.

Have a read on http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: So just chaining them like this `col-md-2 col-xs-4 col-sm-6 ` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. `<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-md-2 grid-item">6</div>`

Comment: That works. Is the `.grid-item` CSS I've used the best way to get the numbers centered in a square-like pattern?

Comment: That's a whole other question and I don't want to go too off topic. You can use `text-align: center;` to align horizontally and there is a great post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div) on Stack Overflow for aligning text vertically.